# Processing Cube through "Analysis Services Processing" Task in SSIS hangs after Compatibility Level in DB Engine changes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2016, cube

After changing the database that feeds the cube from 100 (2008) to 120 (2014), the cubes no longer process (we had to kill the process after taking 5+ hours instead of the usual 10 minutes). The problem is indeed CL change since after reverting back to 100, it fixes the issue.

I have not seen any documentation regarding this issue or I cannot even understand what is the issue, because SSAS was NOT changed at all... the only change was on the DB for the DB-engine side.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from running either a Profiler Session or [server-side trace](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1035/sql-server-performance-statistics-using-a-server-side-trace/), or Extended Events to capture detail about what queries are being ran by SSAS.

SQL Server Management Studio v17+ has a handy built-in Extended Events session called "XEvent Profiler".

Look for long-running queries coming from SSAS, then confirm that statistics have been updated recently for the tables used by those queries.

Have you added RAM or CPU, or made other changes to the SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added RAM actually to SQL Server during the same session. But given the problem goes away completely once I switch back CL, I am not sure if it's related. Also, I didn't think of looking for long-running queries, since I didn't know processing a cube ran any queries. My impression was that it only pumps the cube with data

Comment: You may be able to see blocking happening under the new CL that is not happening under the old CL.  Also, adding RAM can change execution plans quite dramatically, sometimes resulting in poor performance.  [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53726/difference-in-execution-plans-on-uat-and-prod-server) has an interesting example of that.